# User projected field as criteria for a MatchOperation in Spring Boot 2 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I've spent several hours searching for a way to do this but I haven't found any useful.

I'll try to be brief. I have an aggregation with several steps. In first step I group, then I project several fields with expressions (to make some calculations), and finally I want to use those projected fields (the result of my calculations) as a condition in the next match stage:

```
    Cond condOperation = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("productRulesValues.maxTerm").lte("$availableYears"))
            .thenValueOf("$productRulesValues.maxTerm")
            .otherwise("$availableYears");

    TypedAggregation<ProductRulesValues> aggregationProducts = Aggregation.newAggregation(ProductRulesValues.class,
            Aggregation.group("productType")
                    .last("$$ROOT").as("productRulesValues"),
            project("productRulesValues")
                    .andExpression("productRulesValues.maxAge - [0]", formHipooWizard.getAge()).as("availableYears"),
            project("productRulesValues")
                    .and(condOperation).as("duration"),
            new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("productRulesValues.maxTerm").is("$duration"))
    );
```

The closest answer to what I am looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280577/7206287 but it uses the old way with DBObject.

I've tried this way changing DBObject with org.bson.Document since it's what's used now with no luck (it complains about the $where clause). Reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/CriteriaDefinition.html

One thing I dont quite understand is, when I'm defining the first condition there are no issues working with the document attribute and the projected one.

If instead of:

```
new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("productRulesValues.maxTerm").is("$duration")
```

I filter duration with a literal, it works like a charm, so duration has the correct in-memory value :

```
new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("duration").is(30)
```

Any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

The aggregation expressions like in first condition allows you to compare document fields. As such before 3.6 all the match queries are compared to static value and document field.

Starting 3.6 you have to use special opeartor `$expr` which allows use of aggreation expressions inside match queries.

$expr is not supported in spring yet.

You have to use projection to add new field which holds comparison and followed by match operation and extra projection to drop the comparison field.

```
Cond condOperation = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("productRulesValues.maxTerm").lte("$availableYears"))
        .thenValueOf("$productRulesValues.maxTerm")
        .otherwise("$availableYears");

TypedAggregation<ProductRulesValues> aggregationProducts = Aggregation.newAggregation(ProductRulesValues.class,
        Aggregation.group("productType")
                .last("$$ROOT").as("productRulesValues"),
        project("productRulesValues")
                .andExpression("productRulesValues.maxAge - [0]", formHipooWizard.getAge()).as("availableYears"),
        project("productRulesValues")
                .and(condOperation).as("duration").and(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("productRulesValues.maxTerm").equalOf("duration")).as("comp"),
        new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("comp").is(true)),
        project().andExclude("comp");
);
```

Note project with exclusion is supported from 3.4.

Comment: That would do it, thanks! I was thinking on something similar but I guess I was saturated and didn't see it.